# Commutator subgroup $[H,K]$, $H, K$ subgroups of a group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

How could I show that $[H,K]$ is a normal subgroup of $\langle H, K \rangle$? Also that if $H$ is generated by $X$ and $K$ is generated by $Y$, then $[H,K]=\langle g[x,y]g^{-1} | x \in X, y\in Y, g\in \langle H,K \rangle \rangle$?

Comment: What is $\langle H, K \rangle$?

Comment: @s.harp I suspect the smallest subgroup that contains $H$ and $K$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $H,K$ are subgroups then we need to show that $H$ and $K$ normalize $[H,K]$. This just means that $[H,K]$ is a normal subgroup of $\langle H,K\rangle$. By symmetry it suffices to prove that $H\subseteq N_G([H,K])$. Let $h,x\in H$ and $k\in K$. Then $[hx,k]=[h,k]^x[x,k]$, and so $[h,k]^x=[hx,k][x,k]^{-1}\in [H,K]$. Hence conjugation by $x\in H$ maps each of the generators $[h,k]$ of $[H,K]$ back to $[H,K]$, and thus we have $[H,K]^x\subseteq [H,K]$. It follows that $[H,K]^x=[H,K]$, the reverse containment following by replacing $x$ by $x^{-1}$.

Comment: Thanks! This is very helpful!

Comment: You are welcome.